# Why do I get syntax error when i try to execute a stored procedure from session?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The same procedure which I have applied to DB and fro my testcase, I save the stored procedure in a file and trying to execute it in memory (I'm using sqlalchemy with sqlite inmemory DB for the tests).

My stored procedure in a file (ie: storedproc.sql) is like this:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE escalatealarm(IN client_id varchar(50), IN lpriorityid int(5),
IN escalation_time int(10))
BEGIN

 SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl(....
```

I call the stored procedure like:

```
 db.session.execute(open("./resources/storedproc.sql").read())
```

I get following exception:

> OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "PROCEDURE": syntax error

Why do I get this error? I have run the same procedure in mysql server.

I have tried several options like

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `escalatealarm
```

but getting same syntax error.

Comment: have you tried displaying the procedure you read?

Comment: Er, sqlite doesn't do stored procedures. What gave you the idea it did? Whatever it was is something you should drop like a hot potato.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Yes, I didnt see any difference in syntaxes

Comment: @Shawn any other way i can do this? because i need this for my unit test

Comment: I see you mentioned mysql. If you're using that in production, use it in testing too. Having a different infrastructure in test completely defeats the point because you're no longer testing what you're actually using.

Comment: @Shawn for testing all test cases uses sqllite in memeory db.SO you are saying i ca not use sqllite inmemory db for this test?

Comment: Again, if you're using MySQL, test with MySQL, not a completely different product that doesn't act the same way.

Comment: @Shawn I got it. May be this is off topic, but what is the best practice to test DB function storedprocedure calls in unittests which are embedded with CI/CD build? Do we need to have seperate DB environment for testcases?